# How to replace/add key pair for a Windows EC2 instance

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, key-pair

I have a running Windows server image on EC2.

I created an additional administrator login and have been using it login using RDP. Unfortunately I've lost the PEM file for the "Administrator" account and I've also disabled it for "safety"

Since I have access to the instance through an alternative administrative account I'm trying to figure out a few things:

1. Do need the "Administator" account PEM file in future?
2. If I get Amazon to generate a new PEM file using the same name that I currently have, how do I replace the "Administrator" key pair for the instance?

I've searched all over and can't find an answer on how to replace the key pair or add an additional key pair to a running "Windows" instance

Everything talks about shutting down and creating an new instance. I cannot shut down this server, so that must be a way to replace the key pair for the "Administrator" account.

I can't even find where Windows stores the key pair in a Windows server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an instance is first launched from one of the Amazon-supplied Windows AMIs, some code on the instance generates a **random Administrator password**. This password is then encrypted with the selected Keypair and passed back to AWS (you can actually see it in the **System Log**).

When you wish to first login to the instance, you will need to **use the PEM to decrypt the Administrator password**. You can then login to the Windows instance using that password.

It is recommended that you immediately change the Administrator password or connect the instance to Active Directory -- basically, follow your standard company security practices.

If you remember the password, you will not require the PEM file again. In fact, if you change the password, then even having the PEM will not facilitate access because it will only decrypt the *original* password, not the current password.

**Bottom line:** Ignore the PEM file. You still have administrative access to the instance, so you don't even need the Administrator account anymore. If you wish to use the Administrator account, simply use your existing administrative login to reactive it and set the password. There is no reason to panic and, actually, no reason to do anything.